# Flutter: Lock screen in orientation mode

Tags: flutter

I am trying to lock the orientation of the screen, no matter how the device is orientated. It works fine on phone sized devices but does not work on tablet sized devices. Below is my current code.

UPDATE: After further testing it appears to be more specific to devices with a screen ratio of around 4:3 running Android API 29 and 30. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on iPad the documentation is mentionning an issue with setPreferredOrientation, it will not work unless multitasking is disabled :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I've isolated this to devices with a screen ratio of around 4:3 running Android API 29 or 30.